# in php how can I access a index of an array which is stored in a variable as string

Tags: php

```
$row['test']='this is test index';
$test="$row['test']";
echo $test;
```

in the above code in variable **test** I want to store name of the varible **$row['test']** and then try to print **test**. The desired output should be **'this is test index'** but the output I am getting is 
 **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)** . So my question is how can I actually get the value of variable  **$row['test']** stored in the variable **test** as string.

Comment: Just `$test = $row['test'];`. This is extremely basic PHP by the way, you should probably read the [manual on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 1):

Just Remove the double quotations from "$row['test']"
This is works

```
    <?php
    $row['test']='this is test index';
    $test=$row['test'];
    echo $test;
    ?>
```